# Display the row with blank cell at the end of table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to iterate through all the rows in a table client-side, and display the row with empty cell( always on column 3) at the end of the table on page-load. No sorting on any other data or any clicks to sort it. I don't want to use sorttable or tablesorter js since it will sort all the data on column specified.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **:empty** CSS psuedo-class that will match an element which has no children.

Furthermore, you can apply some css to move that element to the end of the row depending on your requirement. Something like

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="elm"></div>
    <div class="elm">Some content</div>
    <div class="elm">Some content</div>
</div>

.elm:empty {
    float: right
}
```

It will apply the above-mentioned CSS to the empty element and will move it to the right.

It's just an example, the actual answer would depend on your codebase.

> No sorting on any other data or any clicks to sort it.

Note: I am assuming that you are aware of the javascript [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method using which you can use to move the empty data to the end of the list by passing a callback to the [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function.